# Create cells value based on formula in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vbscript

I have an Excel sheet like this, is there a way to get value in C8 using C6 in VBA?

[image]

Comment: Next time please include the row and column headers... Also, I've no clue what you're asking, but alas, someone answered so that must be me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non VBA method:

Name the ranges by the their particulars

So, C2 would be `x`, C3 would be `y` and ...

To do this quickly:

1. Highlight B2:C4
2. On the Formula Tab click `Create from Selection`
3. Choose `Left` then hit OK

[image]

This will name the highlighted cells in Column C; x,y,z respectively.

Then your formula in C6 would be:

```
=x*y*1000/z
```

Then in C8:

```
=FORMULATEXT(C6)
```

[image]

---

If that does not work then the following UDFs will do what you want:

```
Function Foo(rng As Range) As String
    Dim MathArr()
    'Add to this array as needed to find all the math functions
    MathArr = Array("*", "-", "+", "/", "(", ")")

    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim strFormula As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Hold two versions of the formula, one manipulate and the other to use.
    strFormula = rng.Formula
    temp = rng.Formula

    'Replace all math functions with space
    For i = LBound(MathArr) To UBound(MathArr)
        strFormula = Replace(strFormula, MathArr(i), " ")
    Next i

    'Split on the space
    strArr = Split(strFormula)

    'iterate and test each part if range
    For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
        If test1(strArr(i)) Then
            'If range then we repace that with the value to the right of that range
            temp = Replace(temp, strArr(i), Range(strArr(i)).Offset(, -1).Value)
        End If
    Next i

    'Return text
    Foo = "=" & temp

End Function

Function test1(reference As String) As Boolean
Dim v As Range

' if the string is not a valid range it will throw and error
On Error Resume Next
Set v = Range(reference) 'try to use referenced range, is address valid?
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    Exit Function 'return false
End If
On Error GoTo 0
test1 = True
End Function
```

Without the ranges being named, so the formula in C6 is `=C2*C3*1000/C4`, I put this in C8:

```
=Foo(C6)
```

[image]

Comment: I have no words to thank you. Really. Thanks a ton!

Comment: However VBA code gives an error that test1 isn't defined.

Comment: Did you out both functions in the same module. There are two?  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.